# ROS2 Humble has a higher CPU usage than Foxy

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, ros-foxy

I migrated from ROS2 Foxy to ROS2 Humble, but I found that the CPU usage has increased significantly. As shown in the figure below, the CPU usage of the `ros2 topic hz` command has increased from around 15% to around 21%. What could be the reason for this?
(Nvidia Jetson NX, Ubuntu 18.04)

**Foxy:**
[image: topic hz on Foxy]

**Humble:**
[image: topic hz on Humble]

---

And this is the result of my test on an armv7 architecture Ubuntu 20.04, using fastdds. As can be seen, the difference is more pronounced now, with the CPU usage of Humble being twice as high as Foxy. I highly suspect it to be an issue with the rclpy library.
[image]

[image]

---

If I use C++ to receive, the CPU usage remains largely unchanged, with Humble even slightly lower. Hence, I am more suspicious that the issue lies with rclpy. It is likely that `ros2 topic hz` is also implemented using Python.

**Humble:**
[image]

**Foxy:**
[image]

Comment: Isn't Humble officially supported on Ubuntu 22.04?